# A problem in modeling the emissions in SUMO

Tags: sumo

Trying to model vehicles' emissions, I used the HBEFA model. There is an issue when the vehicles stop( the first two seconds in my scenario) or decelerate so that no emissions data are recorded during these situations. While I replaced my emission models with PHEMlight, I noticed that getting the license from TU Graz is a must for modeling the buses' emissions which is not possible for me at the moment. Do you have any idea to solve this issue?
regards,
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is an open bug in SUMO see https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/2110 and the references therein. There is currently no good workaround except for manually adapting the emission values after the run for those vehicles by using the emissions for a slow moving bus. I will try to resolve this for the next release though